# How to build a 6-blocks piston extender in 1.20+ Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been searching for online tutorial to build a 6-blocks piston extender in 1.20 Minecraft Java Edition. The closest one that I have found is this one which is 5 blocks.

I would like to know is there anyway to make a 6-blocks extender, preferably compact and expandable.

And here are some designs that I have tried. The left one is 4 blocks, right one is 3 blocks which I like it quite a lot since it is simple. I try to modify them into 6 blocks but it does not work.  [image]

Comment: For large piston extenders like that a flying machine is probably a better option.

Comment: Oh ya! I didn't even think about that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Generally the best way to build large (4+ block) piston extenders is with flying machines. Here is a simple vertical design that can be extended to any length. It is tileable with alternating slime and honey blocks, but only if the flying machines are moved in unison.

[image: 6 block vertical piston extender]

When the lower button is pressed the flying machine is activated, and it moves upwards until it hits the top obsidian. The upper button activates the flying machine again, moving it back to the bottom obsidian.

[image: Piston extender when extended]